# Like button analog (Embeddable widget in Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget

I'm creating embeddable widget, analog of facebook's like button.

I have two **models**: widget and widget_like.

**My db**

In widget table there are websites installed my "like button".

In widget_like table there are website's likes.

***WidgetsController***

```
  def show
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:id])
    @like = WidgetLike.new
  end
```

***WidgetLikesController***

```
  def create
    @widget = Widget.find(params[:widget_id])
    @like = @widget.widget_likes.build(params[:widget_like])
    if @like.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

***widgets/show.js.erb***

```
document.write("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "embed").html_safe) %>");
```

***widgets/embed.html.erb***

```
<%= form_for ([@widget, @like]), :remote => true do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "widget" %>
<% end %>
```

The **problem** is that i need my full url in action of my form. How to add that, and is it safe?

Comment: what do you mean by "my full url in action of my form" ? do you mean that you need the url from the current page where your button sits ?

Comment: i mean something like <form action="http://website.com/widgets/1/widget_likes"> beacuse this form will come to me from a different website

Comment: updated my answer with an even simpler solution. + i just think of it: using `remote: true` will not work well unless you include the rails_ujs script with you form, which seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `url` option of `form_for` :

```
form_for [@widget, @like], remote: true, url: { host: "http://somewebsite.com" }
```

it works exactly like [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/url_for), and should merge the options you provide with the defaults provided by `form_for`.

**UPDATE**

now that i think of it, there's even simpler :

```
form_for [@widget, @like], remote: true, url: { only_path: false }
```

this will get you a full url for the current host. This solution would be easier to maintain.